# Phpmailer = DKIM key not valid with attached file

Tags: phpmailer, attachment, dkim

I try to validate mails sent by phpmailer with DKIM

When there is no attached file and no embedded image, everything is ok, the DKIM key is perfectly valid.

But when I attach a simple pdf file => the DKIM key is not valid

The mail look ok, the attached file is correctly sent, the key is different with and without the attached file so phpmailer includes the file when it computes the key.

Any idea where to search solutions ?

Comment: Does the failure message say which field failed? Is the attachment listed as being signed?

Comment: The only failure message is from the dkim validator I use which says "DKIM key is not valid"

Comment: The attachment files are in the $body var before hashing and signing like this :

--b1_cee7696e4d47cf98af3d607cada12f7a
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="Convocation_AG_Gums_2015.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Convocation_AG_Gums_2015.pdf

**** Content of the attachment file base64 encoded ****

--b1_cee7696e4d47cf98af3d607cada12f7a--

Comment: There are a couple ([1](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/234), [2](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/72)) of DKIM-related issues in the project. As you're finding - DKIM is really difficult to debug!